# List Azure resources integrated with a Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have set up a Virtual Network (VNet) in Azure with multiple subnets. I'm also using VNet Integration  in multiple App Services to this VNet. The App Services are running on different App Service Plans.

Is there a way of listing up all the App Services (and possibly other Azure resources) that are using VNet Integration on this VNet? I know that I can look at the VNet Integration in the networking settings on each App Service, but this approach is too cumbersome when there are hundreds of App Services to look through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a script to list all App Services and Function Apps with VNet Integration enabled in your subscription. Reference from [this blog](https://blog.ivemo.se/Inventory-App-Services-enabled-for-VNet-Integration/).

```
$AppServices = @(
az webapp list | ConvertFrom-Json
az functionapp list | ConvertFrom-Json
)
$VNetAppServices = foreach ($App in $AppServices) {    
    $Apps = az webapp vnet-integration list --n $App.Name -g $App.ResourceGroup
    if ($Apps -ne "[]") {
        $ServerFarm = $App.appServicePlanId -split '/'
        $VNetIntData = $Apps | ConvertFrom-Json
        $VNet = $VNetIntData.VnetResourceID -split '/'
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            AppServiceName = $App.Name
            ServerFarm     = $ServerFarm[8]
            ResourceGroup  = $App.ResourceGroup
            Location       = $App.Location
            VNetName       = $VNet[8]
            SubnetName     = $VNetIntData.name  
            VNetRG         = $VNet[4]       
        }
    }    
}
$VNetAppServices | ft
```

[image]